# Why is it that if $A \subseteq B$ then $\overline{A} \subseteq B$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In a solution that I was reading, we were required to prove that $$\overline{A} \subseteq f^{-1} (f(A)) \tag{$*$}$$

The author did (roughly speaking) the following.

1. First prove that $A \subseteq f^{-1} (f(A))$.
2. Claimed that since $\overline{A}$ is the smallest closed set containing $A$, the result $(*)$ follows.

But I see no reason why this should be the case. We absolutely have $A \subseteq \overline{A}$ so I understand the implication $$\overline{A} \subseteq B \Rightarrow A \subseteq B$$

But I do not see how the other way works, namely

$$A \subseteq B \Rightarrow \overline{A} \subseteq B$$

which is precisely what the author used.

For your reference, I have included a screenshot of the question and answer below.

[image]

Comment: The author uses the fact that $A\subset B$ *and* $B$ is closed implies $\bar A \subset B$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$B$ is not just any set $B=f^{-1}\left(\overline{f(A)}\right)$ that is a closed set because it is the inverse image of a closed set $\overline{f(A)}$ by a continuous function $f$. So the closure of $A$ Being the smallest closed set containing $A$ is contained in $B$